# Delay a Facebook post using the Social Framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, social-framework

I have a project that uses the iOS 6's Social Framework to post to the user's Facebook. All of a sudden, the client asks that I implement a delay between when the user posts the message and when the message is actually posted. The wall post is a sort of advertisement that the user is about to attend a 1.5 hour class at a school, and the client fears that if the user lets everybody know that they're about to be out of the house for a couple hours, somebody will break into their house.

Well anyway, I've poked at this for a while now and I can't see a way to do it. The Social Framework brings up a controller with the details of the wall post where the user can press a Post button. The problem is that I can't access this controller, and I can't find anywhere else to insert a delay. Does anybody have any ideas, or any way to manipulate the controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from manually trying to access the view controller's hierarchy, you are SoL. The social framework isn't mature enough yet to have support for changing what exactly goes on in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using `SLRequest` instead of the built in Share sheet Apple provides to post the status.

Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569124/using-slrequest-in-ios-6-with-facebook) to send the post

And here is the documentation for [SLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)