# In iOS, how do I implement the iOS Facebook login, not the "popup" login?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

Right now, I'm using SDK 4.0 for iOS. (using the simple Button login).

The problem is that on my simulator, even when I have Facebook logged in to the system, my implementation still pops up Safari to authorize the app.

Is there a way to use the "native" Facebook login that doesn't require multiple pop ups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SLRequest` that used `SocialNetwork` framework is a way you can check you native login without help of `Facebook SDK` and perform some action according.

May following links will help you to find your solution.

[How to integrate Facebook in iOS 6 using SLRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757449/how-to-integrate-facebook-in-ios-6-using-slrequest)

[Using SLRequest in iOS 6 with Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569124/using-slrequest-in-ios-6-with-facebook)

[Using SLRequest in iOS 6 with Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569124/using-slrequest-in-ios-6-with-facebook)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new app on the Facebook Developers website and reset your Facebook App Name and Id strings in your plist.  Also make sure you have the brand spankin newest version of the Facebook app installed.  After doing that it should go into "App switching" mode.

This should fix your problem.